# Value no funciona con ngModel

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estoy queriendo poner un valor dentro del input

Funciona con el [value]="" y pongo la variable y sí lo pongo

**#typeLicense="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="clientes.typeLicense"**

por ejemplo dentro del input, desaparece el valor :c

¿Cómo poner el valor por default en el input?

Angular según yo es el nueve

Comment: Agrega el código del html y del ts

Comment: estimado, ponga en su pregunta el input completo que esta utilizando

Answer (score 0):

Me imagino que debes de tener una variable, en el lado ts,

```
public clientes: any = {
.....,
typeLicense:'valor por defecto',
......
}
```

Puede ser una opción.
Espero que te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Fijate en este ejemplo, te podria ayudar.

```
 import {Component} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'example-app',
      template: `
        <input [(ngModel)]="name" #ctrl="ngModel" required>

        <p>Value: {{ name }}</p>
        <p>Valid: {{ ctrl.valid }}</p>

        <button (click)="setValue()">Set value</button>
      `,
    })
    export class SimpleNgModelComp {
      name: string = '';

      setValue() { this.name = 'Nancy'; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero tienes que definir la variable clientes.typeLicense en el archivo .ts, luego con el [(ngModel)] el input va a tomar el valor de la variable, no es necesario el value. Espero te sirva.

```html
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="clientes.typeLicense">
```